# Getting whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map' could not be found

Tags: django, whitenoise

When I am using whitenoise to host my static files, after entering the python manage.py collecstatic command I am getting this error:

```
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'vendor/bootswatch/default/bootstrap.min.css.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x0000029983D66570>.
```

but when I remove all the whitenoise configurations it works collects all the static files successfully.

Below are white noise and static files config in my settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR /'static']

STATIC_ROOT = "static_root"
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [    
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',    
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

```
STORAGES = {    

    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT), set it to `FALSE` in the `settings.py` file and you won't get the error.

Comment: You mean like this:
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False

Comment: Yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage", 
    },
}
```

instead of this:

```
STORAGES = {    

    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).